# LDAP schema objectclass multiple inheritance confuses me

Tags: ldap, openldap, schema

I have set up OpenLDAP 2.4.50 on alpine 3.12.1 and fed `cosine`, `inetorgperson` and `nis` LDIF schemas to it using `ldapadd`. Now I wanted to add a custom object class. I added an entry `cn=mystuff,cn=schema,cn=config`, objectclass `olcSchemaConfig` which worked fine. Now I wanted to add an new objectClass that would provide me some kind of account class with extra information. The idea is simple: create an objectClass that inherits from `person` as well as `posixAccount`. Her goes my LDIF...

```
dn: cn={4}mystuff,cn=schema,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcObjectClasses
olcObjectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.999999.1.2.3 NAME 'myAccount' DESC 'A full acc
 ount as I want it.' SUP ( person $ posixAccount ) STRUCTURAL )
```

The problem is that OpenLDAP wouldn't let me. It states `olcObjectClasses: user-defined ObjectClass has inappropriate SUPerior: "posixAccount"`

I suppose multiple inheritance is not allowed in LDAP the way I'm trying to use it but I couldn't find any reference telling me why.

To make a long story short: how can I create an objectClass that comprises of both, `person` and `posixAccount`? And if it's not possible, please tell me exactly why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution myself reading through https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4512 . The objectClass I am trying to create is `STRUCTURAL` whereas one of the super classes (`posixAccount`) is `AUXILIARY`. Following the RFC this is not allowed:

[section 2.4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4512#section-2.4.2) states

> *"Structural object classes cannot subclass auxiliary object classes."*

and furthermore [section 2.4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4512#section-2.4.3) states

> *"Auxiliary object classes cannot subclass structural object classes."*

In the end this means that multiple inheritance of an object class never works if your super classes are mixed regarding `STRUCTURAL` and `AUXILIARY`. I cannot see a good reason for this but nevertheless it's simply not possible by specification.

Comment: Great that you were able to solve it. But it seems like you accidently created a second account. You should [have your accounts merged](https://serverfault.com/help/merging-accounts), so you can accept your answer. Otherwise the question will stay as "unanswered" in the system.

Comment: I realized that something's amiss here account-wise and have e-mailed support already. Once the merge is complete, I will. Thanks for pointing me to it!

Answer (score 1):

I think you’re running into this limitation https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4512#section-2.4.2

> *”An object or alias entry is characterised by precisely one structural object class superclass chain which has a single structural object class as the most subordinate object class.”*

Comment: Thank you for you answer @HermanB . I'm afraid this is not about object or alias entries, but about object classes. I very much appreciate your efforts tho.